# DirectX HLSL 9 Equalent to Opengl GLSL mat3*vec3

Tags: opengl, directx, shader

I'm trying to rewrite a shader I have in OpenGL that does:

```
vec3 somevariable = mat3*vec3;
```

mat3 and vec3 would be two variables of that type, however when i tried do:

```
float3x3 * float3
```

I get error in HLSL which is fine but when I try convert the math to:
(where `ca = mat3` and no would be the `vec`3) (`float3x3` `float3`)

```
float3 somevariable = float3(ca[0].x*no.x+ca[0].y*no.y+ca[0].z*no.z,ca[1].x*no.x+ca[1].y*no.y+ca[1].z*no.z,ca[2].x*no.x+ca[2].y*no.y+ca[2].z*no.z);
```

This gives a different output than `mat3*vec3` does in OpenGL, anyone know why? thanks :3

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be differences between GLSL and HLSL in terms of whether matrices are row-major or column-major.

Without seeing the error, I would assume your have dimension mismatches. You will need to define your vector as float1x3 or swap your vector and matrix:

1. `float3x3 * float1x3` or `float3x3 * transpose(float3)`
2. `float3 * float3x3`